# Django ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am currently running a Django site on ec2. The site sends a csv back to the client. The CSV is of varying sizes. If it is small the site works fine and client is able to download the file. However, if the file gets large, I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I am guessing this is because the connection is aborting without giving adequate time for the process to run fully. Is there a way to increase this time span?

Here's what my site is returning to the client.

```
with open('//home/ubuntu/Fantasy-Fire/website/optimizer/lineups.csv') as myfile:
                response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='text/csv')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=lineups.csv'
                return response
```

Is there some other argument that can allow me to ignore this error and keep generating the file even if it is taking awhile or is large?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have any sort of backend proxy server which resets the connection to the Django backend and returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` for the case. You should re-configure timeouts on your backend proxy. Usually that is `nginx` or `apache` used as a reverse proxy server.

> **What is Reverse Proxy Server**
>
> A reverse proxy server is an intermediate connection point positioned at a network’s edge. It receives initial HTTP connection requests, acting like the actual endpoint.
>
> Essentially your network’s traffic cop, the reverse proxy serves as a gateway between users and your application origin server. In so doing it handles all policy management and traffic routing.
>
> A reverse proxy operates by:
>
> - Receiving a user connection request
> - Completing a TCP three-way handshake, terminating the initial connection
>   Connecting with the origin server and forwarding the original request

More info at https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/reverse-proxy/

One more possible case - your reverse proxy backend server doesn't have enough free space to process response from Django and aborts the request. You can also check free space on your reverse proxy balancer.

Comment: I am not currently using nginx or apache. Just gunicorn. And it works for smaller files. But as the file grows larger (since it is generated on runtime), at a certain point that error occurs.

Comment: Try to check the gunicorn logs, I believe there should be something interesting for debugging

Comment: I checked both the gunicorn.err.log and gunicorn.out.log and neither one has anything pertaining to this issue since the last record was about 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Within gunicorn, there is an argument for timeout, -t. When you run gunicorn, the default timeout is 30 seconds. Increase that to something your comfortable with like 90 or 120 seconds, whatever you think fits your application.